# horizontal bar using achart engine in android without x and y labeling

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Hi I want to make following graph using achart engine in android ? how to make average score and topper score labes[image]

I dont need x and y labeling.

Comment: I don't think that u can do this with achartengine , probably u should use native views.

Comment: @keshav thanks for answering.
using native views how can i show average score , topper score ?

Comment: U will need to draw dynamic views with specific height and width .